# Attaching build configuration to template via API [TeamCity]

Tags: powershell, automation, teamcity, webclient, teamcity-10

I'm trying to attach a build configuration to a template. We're running TeamCity 10.0.2, using PowerShell 4.0 to interact with it.

According to the [TeamCity 10 API documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API), the attachment of builds to templates operation is possible:

> Read, detach and attach a build configuration from/to a template:
>   GET/DELETE/PUT
>   http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/buildTypes//template 
>   (PUT accepts template locator with the "text/plain" Content-Type)

So I'm trying to attach the `build12` build configuration to the `template12` template, the code I'm doing this with is as follows

```
$webclient             = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$creds                 = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user1","pass1")
$webclient.Credentials = $creds
$webclient.headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain") 
$webclient.UploadString("http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/build12/template", "PUT", "TemplateId")
```

But I keep getting the following error back:

```
Exception calling "UploadString" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
```

Has anyone been able to attach build configurations to templates through the API?

Answer (score 0):

I see you using PowerShell, but you're dropping down the the C# `WebClient` class to do it. Don't do that :)

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/YourBuildId/template -Credential $credential -Method Put -Headers @{"Content-Type"="text/plain"} -Body Your_Template
```

This will attach the template `Your_Template` to your build called `YourBuildId`

If you need help with the `-Credentials` param or anything else, let me know.

I've actually got it to work using the above...